# Prove the formula using "complete induction"

Tags: induction

> Let $S _ { n } = 2 \cdot S _ { n - 1 } + S _ { n - 2 }$  with $S _ { 1 } = 3$ and $S _ { 2 } = 7$.
>   Prove that for every integer $n \geq 1$
>   $$S _ { n } = \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 + \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 } + \frac { 1 } { 2 } ( 1 - \sqrt { 2 } ) ^ { n + 1 }$$

Hint: What are the solutions of the equation $x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1 ?$ Using these solutions will
simplify the proof.

My working:

$$\frac { S _ { n } } { S _ { n - 2 } } = 2 \frac { S _ { n - 1 } } { S _ { n - 2 } } + 1$$

$$x ^ { 2 } = 2 x + 1$$

$$x = \frac { - ( - 2 ) \pm \sqrt { ( - 2 ) ^ { 2 } - 4 ( 1 ) ( - 1 ) } } { 2 ( 1 ) }= \frac { 2 \pm \sqrt { 8 } } { 2 }$$
that is
$1 + \sqrt { 2 }$ or $1 - \sqrt { 2 }$.

Question. I'm stuck here. Someone suggested 
proof by  complete induction but if I test $n=1$ I will get $S_{0}$ which is outside the range $n \geq 1$.

Comment: You haven't supplied initial conditions for the $S_n$.  Assuming you set them so that they match those of the Geometric Sequence then all you have to show is that the latter satisfies the same recursion as the former.

Comment: First of all, if we don't know $S_1$ and $S_2$, we can't deduce any term.

Comment: I had edited the question and added $S _ { 1 } = 3$ and $S _ { 2 } = 7$

Comment: I'm not sure what you might mean by "if I test $n=1$ I will get $S_0$ which is outside the range $n \ge 1$". If you test $n=1$ you get $S_1=\frac{1}{2}(1+\sqrt{3})^2 + \frac{1}{2}(1-\sqrt{3})^2=3$.

Comment: The recursion formula $S_n = 2 S_{n-1} + S_{n-2}$ is intended to apply *only* for $n \ge 3$.

Comment: Ohhh, I get it now , thanks